# Why does the 'if score > 3:' part of this script not work?

Tags: python

I want this script to print "well done" 5 times if the player has a score greater than 3, but it's not working. Please help!

```
score = 0
print "This quiz is based around the video game series, Metal Gear."
person = raw_input("Before we start, please enter your name: ")
print("Lets begin", person)
print "A. 1995"
print "B. 2000"
print "C. 2002"
print "D. 1999"
Q1 = raw_input ("What year did the Outer Heaven Revolt take place?")
if Q1 == "A" or Q1 == "a":
        print "You are correct!"
        score = score+1
else:
    print "Wrong! The correct answer was A"
print "A. Liquid Ocelot"
print "B. Liquid Snake"
print "C. Big Boss"
print "D. Colonel Volgin"
Q2 = raw_input ("Who is the main antagonist in Metal Gear Solid 1?")
if Q2 == "B" or Q2 == "b":
    print "You are correct!"
    score = score+1
else:
    print "Wrong! the correct answer was B"
print "A. Raiden"
print "B. Venom Snake"
print "C. Vamp"
print "D. Sunny"
Q3 = raw_input ("Who is the character with a cyborg body?")
if Q3 == "A" or Q3 == "a":
    print "You are correct!"
    score = score+1
else:
    print "Wrong! the correct answer was A"

print ("Thank you for playing", person)
print ("You have a score of", score)
if score > 3:
    print "Well done / Well done / Well done / Well done / Well done"
```

Comment: Your program only ever produces a score between 0 and 3, but you test if it is **higher** than 3.

Comment: Don't just tell us something is not working. Tell us what you expected to happen, and what happens instead. Include any full tracebacks you get if there is an exception.

Comment: The Equality operator is bette`==` would be an interesting approach to checks for your value equality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone playing your quiz can only ever reach a score of 3. It can never be *greater* than 3, so your `if score > 3:` test is never true. That test would only pass if `score` was set to 4 or higher.

Change the test to use equals instead, so `==`:

```
if score == 3:
    print "Well done / Well done / Well done / Well done / Well done"
```

Comment: Sorry about the informality, this has been my first post on this awesome site <3 and I have it solved now, so thanks for the help! =D